# Solana airdrop error, need help to fix my problem

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, solana, solana-cli

When I type this in the command prompt:

```
solana airdrop 2 -k ./Wallet/.config/solana/Seller.json
```

I get this error

```
Requesting airdrop of 2 SOL
Error: airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached.
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 10):

you need to specify that you are on devnet.

```
solana airdrop 1 -k ./Wallet/.config/solana/Seller.json --url devnet
```

or if you are using pubkey

```
solana airdrop 2 6x5S2cL7fDwM27J7qmfActNJqXj3QcTeoyNTY8Gcujiq --url devnet
```

- if you have a local node running with `solana-test-validator`, then

  ```
  solana airdrop 2 6x5S2cL7fDwM27J7qmfActNJqXj3QcTeoyNTY8Gcujiq
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Airdrops are typically limited to 1 SOL, so you can run:

```
$ solana airdrop 1 -k ./Wallet/.config/solana/Seller.json
```

Otherwise, the error says `This can happen when the rate limit is reached.`, so you may also need to back off and wait.

Comment: Thanks - could you add a link/reference for the 1 SOL limit?

Comment: Certainly! https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-start#airdrop--check-validator-balance

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to get the airdrop running is specifying the URL at the end
like so, if you have a local node running you need to specify --url localhost at the end and same for devnet & testnet, this hack worked for me.`you can specify any amount on localhost but for devnet and testnet you must stay below or equal <=1 Sol`

```
solana airdrop 100000 7LUbP4BZQiopPposQUW7JBrKJ2vgrv7drjbTeFRAb5TS --url localhost
solana airdrop 1 7LUbP4BZQiopPposQUW7JBrKJ2vgrv7drjbTeFRAb5TS --url devnet
solana airdrop 0.5 7LUbP4BZQiopPposQUW7JBrKJ2vgrv7drjbTeFRAb5TS --url testnet
```

Answer (score 1):

I had count the same issue. I just fix network and solved it.

before (It it a error occured)

```
$ solana airdrop 0.1 54jwuH3B7q7J3iv6zbC2CXc2VVeBxTMUdYqh3A8NEvfG --url devnet
```

after

```
$ solana airdrop 0.1 54jwuH3B7q7J3iv6zbC2CXc2VVeBxTMUdYqh3A8NEvfG --url testnet
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me, reached the limit by mistake and need it for urgent test something, you can use the airdrop provide by Quicknode here: https://faucet.quicknode.com/solana/devnet

Just place your address wallet in Devnet and click "Continue", then click on "No thanks, just send me 1 SOL."

Answer (score 0):

You Could Also Try Airdropping a Smaller Amount like 0.1 If It's Still Not Working..

```
solana airdrop 0.1 pubkey --url devnet
```

Answer (score 0):

As already described by multiple members, if you are using a testnet or a local setup, you need to specify that.

For example, if you are running local validator with the following command:

```
solana-test-validator
```

Then, you should point your Solana CLI utility to it with

```
solana config set --url localhost
```

And then, you can run normal airdrop command

```
solana airdrop 2
```

[Screenshot of these commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8igI.png)

You can learn to create a [local Solana setup network setup](https://web3coda.com/labcontent/?name=solana-test-setup) with hands-on exercises using this resource.